# calculating diversity by groups

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot shannon diversity for BTO data, however, to use the `vegan` package, I must place the data into matrix form. This is not a problem, however, I have various variables to group shannon diversity by however, I'm having difficulties subsetting this into code.

I need a way to calculate diversity by `localicity_id + Postcode + week + year`, using this code:

```
diversity <- diversity(method_one[, 5:150], index = "shannon", base = exp(1))
```

I have tried using the `groups` function embedded in the `diversity` function, however, it will not work for me, could be that I am doing it wrong. I attached `groups = week` at the end of the code.

reproducible code, I have only taken the first 25 columns as opposed to 150:

```
structure(list(LOC_ID = c("LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", 
"LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", 
"LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", 
"LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", 
"LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", 
"LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", 
"LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", 
"LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", 
"LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", 
"LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", "LOC2670044", 
"LOC2670044", "LOC2670044"), week = c(34, 35, 36, 38, 39, 40, 
41, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 51, 52, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 
24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34), year = c(2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019), POSTCODE = c("IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", 
"IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", 
"IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", 
"IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", 
"IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", 
"IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", 
"IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", 
"IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", 
"IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR", "IP20 0HR"
), `Collared Dove` = c(2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 
1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2), Dunnock = c(1, 
0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 0, 
2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 
2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0), Goldfinch = c(1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 
0, 1, 4, 4, 0, 0, 10, 3, 6, 7, 5, 4, 0, 0, 6, 3, 7, 3, 3, 5, 
5, 0, 0, 3, 0, 5, 4, 4, 0, 0, 4, 3, 0, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0
), `House Sparrow` = c(7, 5, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 
3, 3, 0, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 0, 5, 0, 0, 12, 4, 5, 0), Woodpigeon = c(1, 
0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 2, 0, 
3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 3, 2, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 3, 2, 3, 3, 0, 3, 
3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 3, 3), `Great Tit` = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0
), Robin = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 
0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0), Blackbird = c(0, 0, 1, 
2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 
1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 4, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3, 0, 
4, 0, 3, 3, 2), `Blue Tit` = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 9, 4, 0, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0), Wren = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Chaffinch = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 
2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    Greenfinch = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 
    1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0), `Long-tailed Tit` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Starling = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 10, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 2, 9, 6, 0, 0, 
    10, 0, 3, 5, 0, 1, 0, 1), `Song Thrush` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Reed Bunting` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Magpie = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), Sparrowhawk = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0), `Coal Tit` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Pied/White Wagtail` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Fieldfare = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**EDIT:**
I have also tried:

```
diversity(aggregate(. ~ LOC_ID + week + year + POSTCODE  , method_one, sum), MARGIN=1, index="simpson")
```

however it reports that the input datas are not numeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
vals <- diversity(aggregate(. ~ LOC_ID + week + year + POSTCODE  , method_one, sum)[, 5:25], MARGIN=1, index="simpson")
round(vals, 3)
 [1] 0.611 0.617 0.860 0.640 0.876 0.857 0.790 0.778 0.716 0.720 0.778 0.806 0.731 0.800 0.852 0.740 0.612 0.758 0.798 0.840 0.836 0.781 0.833
[24] 0.803 0.833 0.754 0.853 0.741 0.711 0.810 0.826 0.720 0.760 0.810 0.850 0.886 0.778 0.778 0.725 0.862 0.820 0.806 0.796 0.844 0.844 0.881
[47] 0.565 0.875 0.722 0.719
```

You need to remove the first 4 columns of character data before you pass the output from `aggregate` to `diversity`.