# How to take the diversity function and add it as a column

Tags: r

I have been following this code here:
[calculating diversity by groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64251772/calculating-diversity-by-groups)

However, when I implement the code it returns only the values. I have tried `cbind` to put it into another dataframe, however, I am afraid that the rows do not match. Is there a way to run that code, which places it in the same dataframe so the rows match with where they were taken from..

Answer (score 0):

following the code given in the answer linked what you need is to use `right_join` to link the `diversity` vector with the `method_one` data.frame :

```r
diversity(aggregate(. ~ LOC_ID + week + year + POSTCODE  , method_one, sum)[, 5:25], MARGIN=1, index="simpson") %>%
   tibble(diversity=., ID=1:length(.)) %>%
   right_join(method_one %>% mutate(ID=1:nrow(.)))
```

Explanation :

- `method_one %>% mutate(ID=1:nrow(.))` adds an `ID` column.
- `tibble(diversity=., ID=1:length(.))` turns the result of the `diversity` call into a `tibble` with an `ID` column.
- `right_join(x, y, by=NULL, ...)` : return all rows from `y`, and all columns from `x` and `y`. Rows in `y` with no match in `x` will have `NA` values in the new columns. If there are multiple matches between `x` and `y`, all combinations of the matches are returned. if `by==NULL` it will use columns with matching names in this case `ID`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(vegan)
method_one %>%
       group_by(LOC_ID, week, year, POSTCODE) %>%
       summarise(across(everything(), sum, na.rm  = TRUE)) %>%
       ungroup %>%
       select(5:25) %>%
       diversity %>%
       tibble(diversity = .)  %>% 
       bind_cols(method_one, .)
```